# webserver on linode and database on digital ocean

Tags: database, remote-access, ssd, linode, drupal7

Currently hosting drupal websites on linode using apache + php5 fpm+ fastcgi.
Among websites one is drupal commerce(max_execution_time,memory_limit are taken care) and all others are low hitting websites.

Now I am thinking about moving only database(some postgres and some mysql) to digitalocean as they are offering ssd.

Linode size is 1gb,8 core

Digitalocean thinking about 1gb,1core,30g SSD(will be upgrade if number of sites increases)

Is it ok to host a webserver on one server and database on another. My main concern is about response time and server load so that usual errors like "mysql server gone away","php memory limit exceeded" etc. can be controlled.

Answer (score 0):

Principally, it makes no difference where the database is located, be it `localhost`, another machine in the same network or with another provider. Especially, the PHP memory limit will be unaffected.

Nevertheless, you might get a faster DB server but you also get higher network latencies for the SQL traffic and add another dependency to your setup, namely the connection between those providers, making connection issues to the DB somewhat more likely. Also, the SQL traffic needs more/better security compared to using `localhost` or a server in the same network. You also need to maintain more servers at more providers, handle more contracts etc.

Myself, I would consider this only if I had a real performance problem with the database that *will* be solved by using an SSD as backing store, but this would likely result in moving everything to the new provider.

Comment: _moving everything to the new provider_ seems ok but, if i choose 2gb 20$ plan on D.O which offer **only 2 processors**, can it handle drupal's native cronjob+ autobackupmysql+ autobackuppostgresql and other image related compression job etc. If 2 core is enough I will definitely move to D.O.